# List of parameter of request.getHeader(String value)

Tags: java, browser

I need the list of String parameter of **request.getHeader(String value)** .
I already know one which is "User-Agent" (e.g. request.getHeader("User-Agent") )

also for such cases about other methods like this, how do I get the list of parameter of such methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [getHeaderNames()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeaderNames%28%29). It returns an `Enumeration<java.lang.String>` of all the header names the `request` contains.